# Firefox Snap not respecting copy to clipboard after closing it

Tags: firefox, 22.04, snap

I think there is an issue here, although it might be a setting somewhere. You need to be in 22.04 in order to do this:

1. Open Firefox (The snap version)
2. Go to any link you want and then copy the URL from it (Highligh the URL and copy it with CTRL+C for example)
3. Close Firefox
4. Try to paste what you copied to any other app.

You will notice it is gone. The clipboard was emptied when Firefox closed. You can even test this by leaving Firefox opened and pasting in another app, then close Firefox and try to paste again. The clipboard is gone.

Is there a setting for this?

UPDATE: This also affects anything that gets copied from within Firefox and then closing Firefox afterwards. The clipboard will be gone for what was copied before closing Firefox.

Comment: This is standard, expected behavior under X11. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Clipboard_manager#Managers It is also important to realize that according to the selection protocols, nothing is copied until it is pasted. For example, if you select some word in a terminal window, close the terminal and then want to paste it somewhere else, it will not work because the terminal is gone and the text has not been copied anywhere. If you want the word to be preserved after closing terminal window, consider installing a clipboard manager.

Comment: Hi @Quasímodo I would highly disagree with this. I have used Linux for 20 years already and this is the first time seeing this behavior. Closing an app has never ever affected what I had already copied to clipboard.

Comment: Luis, it may be that your setup or even default Ubuntu shipped with a clipboard manager. Furthermore, I think Firefox did actually include a workaround itself to the vanishing clipboard.

Comment: @Quasímodo both of your points are good. I would need to check both on Firefox or Ubuntu for this.but both I think are logical to what is happening. I will update you on my findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a bug report in Bugzilla for Mozilla, but for anyone having the same issue (Assuming again it is a bug and that there is no Flag or option that disallows for security or other reasons to copy outside of Firefox), you can provide more information here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1790282

This affects both, Snap & Deb versions in Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug (Firefox Broken Copy Link Key)  and should be reported to Mozilla. It's not something that can be fixed by - or is a fault with - Ubuntu. The same bug exists with both snap and APT versions.

There's a [link here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) where this can be simply achieved.

Comment: What is the use of linking to a site that then only provides another link?

Comment: Hi Number Guy, the answer was not really helpful as I had already checked for a bug and none was found. I will go the route of "bug" because it is not a very nice thing to have when copying, although I do know there has been several new features integrated in terms of security, so maybe any of them could be an option disallowing this to happen.